# Replace the src of all the images with the value of another tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have built a woocommerce shop and for the images of my products look blurry.

So I inspected the products blocks and found the following:

```
<img class="async-done" src="http://secureservercdn.net/160.153.137.40/w54.501.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Boobs-Mockup-white-uai-258x258.png" width="258" height="258" alt="" data-uniqueid="73120-653948" data-guid="http://secureservercdn.net/160.153.137.40/w54.501.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Boobs-Mockup-white.png" data-path="2019/07/Boobs-Mockup-white.png" data-width="4480" data-height="4480" data-singlew="6" data-singleh="4" data-crop="" data-fixed="" scale="0">
```

The `data-guid` tag contains the full resolution link to the image and the `src` tag contains a generated thumbnail.

How can I replace the `src` tag value with the `data-guid` tag value on all the blocks with the class `async-done` so that the image becomes the high res instead of the generated thumbnail using JQuery?

I tried multiple methods to fix the thumbnail issue from the backend but it keeps on showing a 258x258 version of the image :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$.each($("img.async-done"), function(index, image){
    $(image).attr("src", $(image).data("guid"));
});
```

Also consider doing this with a backdrop in place while the images load up, just so your users have a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (untested):

```
$('img.async-done').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('guid');
});
```

I guess it would be better to do this change in PHP on the server if possible, as if you do it in the browser it will likely load all the thumbnails, then all the images from data-guid, which will waste data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace image because there will be an option in your theme settings to display full size orignal image.

or you can change size from WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > Product Images

or if you are using custom theme then you can use something like this.

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full', false );
```